# Hibernate: @UniqueConstraint with @ManyToOne field?

Tags: hibernate, groovy

Using the following code:

```
@Entity 
@Table(uniqueConstraints=[@UniqueConstraint(columnNames=["account","name"])])
class Friend {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long id
  @ManyToOne
  public Account account
  public String href
  public String name
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (account, name) on table Friend: account not found
```

It seems this has to do with the @ManyToOne constraint, which I imagine actually creates a separate UniqueConstraint???

In any case, if I take this out, there is no complaint about the UniqueConstraint, but there is another error which makes me believe it must be left in.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.mksoft.fbautomate.domain.Account, at table: Friend, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(account)]
```

Any hints how I can create such a desired constraint (i.e., that each combination of account and name occurs only once???)

Thank you!

Misha

Comment: Does @Peter's solution worked for you?

Answer (score 15):

The solution:

```
@Entity 
@Table(uniqueConstraints=[@UniqueConstraint(columnNames=["myaccountcolum","name"])])
class Friend {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="myaccountcolum")
  public Account account
  public String href
  public String name
}
```

Explanation:
The column name for the @ManyToOne in the generated table will probably be something like account_id instead of account.  The @UniqueConstraint expects the exact column name, not the name you use in your class.  To make sure it just works, give this column a specific name with @JoinColumn and make sure the same name is used in your UniqueConstraint.

Answer (score 0):

I use  @JoinColumn and that is OK, but im runing liquibase script "diffAll" and this created .yaml file both mysql and oracle.

Column name is "profile" in mysql and "profile_id" in oracle database.

When i write "@JoinColumn(name="profile")  that is try drop "profile_id" column and add "profile" column for oracle db.

How i created @UniqConstraint for multiple database.

Thank you.
Best regards.