# Hibernate is unable to create my entity table when I add uniqueConstraints

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having some trouble dealing with Hibernate. 
I have an entity like this

```
@Table(name = "level",
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"channel", "name"})})
@Entity
public class LevelEntity implements BaseEntity<Long> {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ChannelEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel")
    @Target(ChannelEntity.class)
    private ChannelEntity channel;


    public LoyaltyLevelEntity() {
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
......
```

When I remove `uniqueConstraints` the table is created when my application is deployed if the table does not exist in the DB. However with presence of this parameter the table is not create by hibernate and I get an exception.

My goal is to have a unique Id Level name for the same channel.

Exception :

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2452)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1706)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)




java.sql.SQLException: ISAM error: no record found.
    com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3876)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2662)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2578)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executePrepare(IfxSqli.java:1397)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.f(IfxPreparedStatement.java:326)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.a(IfxPreparedStatement.java:306)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.<init>(IfxPreparedStatement.java:176)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.h(IfxSqliConnect.java:6707)
    com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(IfxSqliConnect.java:2470)
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: The error is unclear to me. Maybe you are not using the correct column name as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067209/hibernate-uniqueconstraint-with-manytoone-field.